# Cannot send desktop capture to ffserver?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am simply trying to send a `ffmpeg` stream consisting of a desktop capture to a local `ffserver`:

```
 # ffserver >/dev/null 2>&1 &
 # ffmpeg -video_size 1600x900 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa \
   -ac 2 -i hw:0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

I have the following error:

```
[mpeg1video @ 0x55652e5d5da0] MPEG-1/2 does not support 3/1 fps
...
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

**How can I avoid this error and stream my desktop to my ffserver?**

Comment: What does `feed1.ffm` say?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

https://organicdesign.nz/Simple_video_streaming_with_ffserver 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cObC-nNUIwI

You should be able to tailor this info to your needs.

Like:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -s 1600x900 -f x11grab -i :0.0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

and have a separate feed for audio if you want.

And:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0,0 -acodec pcm_s16le http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm
```

Or: Figure out how to get the two to play nice together in a one liner.

Try useing these ACL settings:

```
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
```

With this Command:

```
ffserver >/dev/null 2>&1 &
ffmpeg -video_size 1600x900 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i :0.0 \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0 http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

It seems as though the connection may be being refused because of the word localhost.